# Sprite elements not being updated

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I am trying to program an animation in PYGAME of colored cells that at each iteration a couple of them exchange their respective colors. However, I don't quite understand why, the code generates the grid of cells but there is no movement of any kind. It just stays static.

```
import random
import pygame
import sys

colors = [(77,2,6),(180,5,180),(140,180,11)]

class CELL () :
    def __init__ (self,x,y,ide):
        self.color = random.choice(colors)
        self.ide = ide
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

n, m = 10, 10
block_width, block_height = 50, 50
win_width, win_height = block_width*m, block_height*n
# Matrix : 10x10
# Cell size : 50x50
# Window size : 500x500

cells = {}
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        cells[i*n+j] = CELL(i,j,i*n+j)
# We create a cells dictionary in which keys are the 
# ID attribute of each cell object stored.

class sprite_CELL (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self,cell_obj):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.cell = cell_obj
        # Represents one of the cells.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([block_width,block_height])
        self.update_rect()
    def update_rect (self):
        self.image.fill(self.cell.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # We update the rect according to the current color for the linked cell.
        self.rect.topleft = [self.cell.x*block_width, self.cell.y*block_height]

sprites_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for cell in cells.values():
    sprites_group.add(sprite_CELL(cell))

# So far we have created a group of sprites containing sprites whose method
# "("update_rect" updates their graphical representation depending on the
# color of the cell to which the sprite is linked.

# API

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))

sprites_group.draw(window)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    rand_cell_a = random.choice(list(cells.values()))
    rand_cell_b = random.choice(list(cells.values()))
    # We randomly choose two cells.
    color_a = cells[rand_cell_a.ide].color
    color_b = cells[rand_cell_b.ide].color
    # We extract the colors and...
    cells[rand_cell_a.ide].color = color_b
    cells[rand_cell_b.ide].color = color_a
    # Swap the colors for the cells.

    sprites_group.update()
    # Updating the sprites should update their linked
    # colors too.

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    # And that's done iteratively.
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could solve this for me.

Comment: It is not enough to change the color attribute. You must also call `update_rect`. because you have to fill the image with the new color (`self.image.fill(self.cell.color)`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `update_rect` to `update` after that you need need to put `sprites_group.draw(window)` inside the loop (after the `sprites_group.update()` and before the `pygame.display.flip()`) and the program will work just fine.
The sprites were changing the color but you only draw them once in the beginning of the script so they kept the same color.

Comment: Have you tested copying the original code again and only adding the `sprites_group.draw(window)` line in the correct spot to see if it works? I only done that and it worked for me and @YagoMj. Maybe you changed the function name in the class definition from update to update_rect and thats why. Glad I could help.

Comment: Now I got it, I didn't understand the questions was modified, sorry then.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to redraw the grind in every frame. You have to call `sprites_group.draw(window)` in the application loop:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    sprites_group.draw(window)           # <--- draw grid
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

---

It is not enough to change the color attribute. You must also call `update_rect`. because you have to fill the image with the new color (`self.image.fill(self.cell.color)`):

```py
cells[rand_cell_a.ide].color = color_b
cells[rand_cell_b.ide].color = color_a
for s in sprites_group:
    s.update_rect()
```

---

However, see [`pygame.sprite.Group.update`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the **update()** method on all Sprites in the Group.

I suggest renaming the method from `update_rect` to `update`:

```py
class sprite_CELL (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self,cell_obj):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.cell = cell_obj
        # Represents one of the cells.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([block_width,block_height])
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.image.fill(self.cell.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # We update the rect according to the current color for the linked cell.
        self.rect.topleft = [self.cell.x*block_width, self.cell.y*block_height]
```

So it is sufficient to call `sprites_group.update()`:

```py
cells[rand_cell_a.ide].color = color_b
cells[rand_cell_b.ide].color = color_a
sprites_group.update()
```

Comment: In the code that I originally posted, I already made use of the pygame.sprite.Group() object that you mentioned, to group them and call the update() method on all of them.

Anyway, regardless of the name of the method that updates the sprite (which you will see that I have already changed in the code that I attach), the animation still does not work. The color grid appears on the screen, but they still don't move.

Do you have any guess about that?

Comment: @YagoMj You have to call `sprites_group.draw(window)` in the application loop. (answer updated)